# Do we include Transmission delay in Round trip time?

Tags: computer-networks

Is RTT = $2*T_{Propagation delay}$ only. Or we include Transmission delay to send packets as well. Some examples include Transmission delay some not. I'm confused. Can anyone help.

Comment: Round-trip time is the time it takes for a packet that you send to get back to you. Now you can forget about the formulas, and rederive them to fit the definition.

Comment: Yes I know, but many examples don't take Transmission time into account. @Yuval

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the question is whether the round trip time also includes the transmission delay of the packet? when should we include / not include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have two computers (A and B) both connected to a switch with cut-through forwarding. When you are interested about RTT between computer A and computer B, you'll omit transmission delay, because the switch transmits the frame to B as it arrives from A, so transmission delay is not significant. Now, suppose that our switch uses store-forward, in this case, when the frame arrives, the switch will first store it completely, and then sends it to B, so we have to deal with transmission delay.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, T<sub>RTT</sub> should be 2*T<sub>propogation</sub> + T<sub>transmission</sub>.

Comment: You wrote (2 * T_propagation) + T_transmission, which seems to account for 1 out of 4 serialization delays. Any intermediate routers may do cut-through routing independent of frame size, or may add their own serialization delays. Also, you are modeling scheduling / response time at the far end as zero, which is a fair approximation, but there may be local measurements available to flesh out that term, as well.

Answer (score 0):

RTT is defined as the time it takes for a **small packet** to travel from client to server and back to client. It includes queueing delay, propagation delay and packet processing delay but doesn't include transmission delay. If we talk about TCP 3-way handshake or a request packet from client to server then the size of the packet involved isn't worth counting the transmission delay.

"To this end, we define the round-trip time (RTT), which is the time it takes for a small packet to travel from client to server and then back to the client. The RTT includes packet-propagation delays, packet queuing delays in intermediate routers and switches, and packet-processing delays"

Computer Networks: A Top Down Approach" by James F Kurose
[Above referenced book](https://eclass.teicrete.gr/modules/document/file.php/TP326/%CE%98%CE%B5%CF%89%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%B1%20(Lectures)/Computer_Networking_A_Top-Down_Approach.pdf)

Comment: Please credit the source of the image. Also, please transcribe it to make the text searchable.